# Eliminar usuario con caracteres unicode Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Necesito eliminar un usuario sin embargo al buscarlo mediante una consulta no muestra registros.

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 "DBC".Users
where
    UserName = 'nombreUsuario21'
```

Al ejecutar una segunda consulta filtrada si muestra resultados.

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 "DBC".Users
where
    UserName like 'nombreUsuario21%'
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

> nombreUsuario21

El resultado sin espacios o algun otro caracter, al momento de querer eliminar el usuario.

```
DROP USER nombreUsuario21
```

> Database 'nombreUsuario21' does not exist.

De forma visual se encuentra de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y debe haber algun caracter no visible que te esta molestando. Te deja hacer un update al nombre del usuario como para ver si se puede cambiar?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 "DBC".Users
where
    UserName = RTRIM('nombreUsuario21','0A0D'xc)
```

Si muestra datos significa que hay caracteres no visibles como un salto de linea aunque no lo parezca.